# Load neo4j database with java

Tags: java, load, neo4j

I have a neo4j database ready and I want to make a java app for retrieving data from it.
How can I load this already made database in my program and then query it?
In the code I'm giving below I want to initialize the db object with that database.

thanks in advance

`ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);
String query = "";
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Tutorial in the Neo4j Manual:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node(*) where n.name! = 'my node' return n, n.name" );
```

Make sure to keep the db and execution engine in a shared variable. And to `shutdown()` the db when your program ends.

Comment: I had forgottent to stop the server and tha database was locked.So that's why I had problems with the initiliazation as it is in the neo4j manual. Thank you very much for your answer. You are doing great work with the neo4j tool.